# Simplest way to create regulated 400VDC from 12VDC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

I would like to create a regulated 400VDC supply with relatively low ripple (less than +-1VDC ideally). Required current is very low (< 1mA). V_IN is 12VDC. Currently I have a boost converter that is able to create well above 400VDC based off a NE555 in astable configuration and a small MOSFET. It works very well and I use constant switching frequency (30 kHz) and adjust the duty cycle so that the output voltage is correct.

However, when the source is loaded, the voltage breaks down and I do have slightly varying load and would like to ensure that the output voltage is regulated to around 400VDC. Which approach (IC or discrete) works well and which works the easiest?

Comment: You could use a voltage controlled pwm-generator and an op-amp to make negative feedback

Comment: There's actually quite a few flyback controllers which you could use; step-up is the less common configuration, but as far as I can see, if you "just" exchange primary and secondary of a flyback transformer and adjust the feedback path accordingly, things should work nicely. Onsemi has a lot of flyback controllers, and TI has the nicer packages.

Comment: You are asking us to 'shop' for you, which is off-topic here. It is up to you to shop for suitable flyback controllers based on *your* needs. Come up with a design and post it here, then we can help you.

Comment: I'm not asking for shopping, but hints on concrete and simple ways to realize this (specifying that input/output voltage/current and I'd also like to not wind a transformer). I simply do not *know* any SMPS controller, even less which one I should use.

Comment: http://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/flyback.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current is low .This means that a diode pump could have cheap small caps .Boost converters can be operated into a diode pump .You could make say 50 volts with the boost converter and use a multistage diode pump off the drain to make your needed 400VDC .This does mean 8 pump stages but 4148 diodes and 100n caps are cheap.The advantage of this is that you can use readily available boost chips and a standard garden variety SMD coil because the expected peak to peak volts across the coil is only 50VDC.The boost ratio is not too high so old school hard switching peak current mode will work OK.What I have done also is use a soft switching boost converter made from discretes running a higher boost ratio using BAV21 pump stages at 160 volts per stage .

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of using a normal converter (to a reasonably high voltage) plus a Villard cascade. Great idea!